# Malloc memory in multiprocessing python script is freed but never made available again

Tags: python, c, malloc, python-multiprocessing, coredump

The title is probably very confusing, but I couldn't find a way to synthesized my problem in a single sentence. Basically, I have a Python script that uses pytorch multiprocessing with some libraries that are based on C/C++ programs. This script appears to be leaking memory, as each iteration of my main loop shows increasing memory consumption in top whereas no object (no "big" object to be more precise) should stay referenced between 2 iterations. However, when using python's tracemalloc, almost no memory consumption is visible (~100 MiB while top shows 30 GiB).

That is why I started looking into objects created in C. I ran my script for 1.5 iteration (long enough for it to leak) and aborted it so that it generated a core dump. I read the core dump using [chap](https://github.com/vmware/chap), and found that there is only a little bit of leaked or used memory, but around 21 GB of freed memory :

```
chap> count used
3547398 allocations use 0xa990c7f0 (2,844,837,872) bytes.
chap> count free
34154 allocations use 0x4ff33cc08 (21,461,453,832) bytes.
chap> count leaked
41752 allocations use 0x2cef18 (2,944,792) bytes.
```

It looks like all the memory from the first iteration was freed but stayed unusable for the remainder of the script. It might not be a real memory leak but it behaves like one. My main hypothesis is that there is some kind of weird interaction between python multiprocessing and malloc, which makes the memory allocated and freed from a specific process be unusable by other processes. Therefore, when the process ends after an iteration, there is no way for the rest of the script to use the freed memory.

Does it make any sense ? Is there a way to change this behavior ? It is also very important to note that this problem only appears on one of the machines I run the script on (which the only one using Debian and not CentOS). Besides, I ran the script using jemalloc and it did not produce such leak, so I'm pretty sure this has something to do with malloc.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated, I'm a bit stuck right now.

EDIT:
Here is an illustration of what happens.

```py
mylist = [...]
model = PytorchModel()
for el in mylist:
   ds = PytorchDataset()
   dl = PytorchDataloader(num_workers=32)
   for x, y in dl:
      # Do some things with x, y and model. 
      # x and y are originally C objects but are converted to numpy arrays then torch tensors.
```

For each iteration of the first loop, nothing stays referenced except for the model. The model itself does not store references to objects created inside the loop. This is confirmed by the fact that the allocations are marked as free. The processes allocating the memory are terminated at the end of the second loop but theire "free" memory is never returned to the system.

Comment: Why not try valgrind?

Comment: What do you mean by "increasing memory consumption in top"? top shows a few memory metrics, not all of them are memory consumption.

Comment: Memory allocated and then freed by a process is available for re-use by that process.  Until that process terminates, however, it might or might not be available for *other* processes to use.  This is because there is a difference between (virtual) memory assigned to a process by the OS and memory allocated for use by the program.

Comment: Additionally, it is possible for a perverse memory allocation pattern to force a process to continue acquiring memory from the system to satisfy its allocation requests, despite having lots of free memory available for allocation.

Comment: @n.m. Because I didn't know about it, I might try it now.

Comment: @ElderBug I mean the total amount of memory used. Basically, my memory usage increases over time while it should not.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That is what I understood. But here the process terminates and the memory is never returned to the system. New processes are created at each iteration of my main loop but they can't make use of the old processes' "free memory". I'll edit my post to illustrate a bit better.

Comment: I'll add that I am not a C developer, but I have some understanding of it. I'm just a python developer that happens to use libraries built with C (mainly [cucim](https://github.com/rapidsai/cucim)).

Comment: Do your memory-allocating processes fork themselves?  As opposed to some parent process forking new children as needed?

Comment: As per python's [multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) :
"The parent process uses os.fork() to fork the Python interpreter. The child process, when it begins, is effectively identical to the parent process. All resources of the parent are inherited by the child process. Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is problematic."

It seems that it is the parent process that forks.

Comment: If the best you can do is an assumption that the software stack is top to bottom adhering to best practices, then I don't think we are in a position to help you.  Because very likely, something *isn't* doing that, and we can't determine for you what component that is or what it is doing wrong.

Comment: Well to be honest I'm not sure how I can determine that. The process creation is done entirely by python standard library `os`. Per its documentation, a parent forks its children. I didn't implement any of the multiprocessing functions, and they are all done by completely standard python function (wrapped in pytorch, which is also pretty standard). I can't reallistically be expected to go read the whole source code of python and pytorch to check whether they are incorretly forking processes, especially given they are so widespread that it is very unlikely.

Comment: Besides, as stated in the original post, this script runs totally fine on another server (which has a pretty different config). It also works when I use jemalloc. There is clearly a problem between the way python handles subprocesses and malloc freed memory, but I don't have more info than you on that. I assume python adheres to best practice when it comes to the software stack. But maybe it relies on some lower level os programs that are bugged. The C code that generates these _leaking_ objects is compiled using pip wheels, meaning that it should not depend on the machine it is ran on.

Comment: I can share some hardware and software specs if it might help, I can even share my source code. I already spent 2 full days trying to look into things I barely understand (like core dumps). As I said, I'm not a C developer and have only very basic knowledge of those things, that is why I am asking for help.